# Is it possible to call a VC++ tool using CGI and PHP? and if 'yes' then how to do it?

Tags: web-services, visual-c++, cgi

I have implemented a command line tool with VC++ and now i need to run that tool using web service on windows. So is it possible to do it using PHP and CGI??
If you are having any other solutions to do so, then plz let me know.

Comment: It is very unlikely you will get someone to do the entire work for you. You are much more likely to get a good answer if you try something first and then if it fails you ask us about it with your code, what expected behavior you expected and what actual behavior you got.

Answer (score 0):

Use `IIS's` **Handle Mappings** and add a **Add Script Map** or **Add Wildcard Script Map**. Setup your `service.exe` there and keep going.

Or use `PHP` with [`exec()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.exec.php).

`PS`: *You might have to deal with Access Privileges and such in Windows for this. Can't really help you there.*

**Another way to do this is** to make your service interact only with the database and have your front end setup work and display progress while the service is independent from it and deals only with the database.